# Akka Stream: Which one is better - scan or scanAsync?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am a newbie to Akka Stream, so apology, if I ask any stupid question.

I was going through the Akka Stream [QuickStart guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-quickstart.html). And I found `scan` operation. The documentation says that it is similar to `fold` but is not a terminal operation. I got that part, but when I found `scanAsync` then the documentation said the same thing, except for one thing, i.e., it is similar to `scan` but with an asynchronous function.

Now, my doubts are:

1. What is the difference between them? and,
2. Which one is the better one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The main difference between them is that result of the given function `f` is different. The output value of the f function in the case with **scanAsync** is **Future**. So the next computation will begin as soon as the **Future** will be completed. But, when using **scan** computation of the next value will begin immediately after the computing of the current one.
2. General answer: it depends. However here is some advice: You should use **scan** when computation of the next value depends only on CPU and there is no temporary disk/network read/writes, and use **scanAsync** otherwise

Hope it helped!!!

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I have one doubt - does `scanAsync` tells about the exact `Future` computation at which failure occurred?

Comment: @himanshuIIITian I don't quite understand what you mean, but Scala Future always provides either Success or Failure return value. So I think, yes.

Comment: @akauppi What I meant was - `scanAsync` works on a series of `Future`, right? So, would it tell me which `Future` operation failed out of many?

Comment: I don't think it's its job to do so. Depends on how you treat those Futures later (e.g. run an onComplete on them, and there be able to detect an error). It's your job to provide the Future's an identifying value (flow id, maybe index; you can use .zip and .zipWithIndex for this); then you will be able to tell them apart in the onComplete.   Anyways, this is speculative and outside of your original question which I think got answered.

Comment: Ok - I see. I was expecting `akka-streams` to provide it out of the box.

Comment: But with `scan` the input to the next computation depends on the output of the current computation. So how can the next one start before the `Future` has completed?